# search for element name using PHP simple HTML dom parser

Tags: php, dom, xml-parsing

I'm hoping someone can help me. I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) successfully, but I now am trying to find elements based on a certain name. For example, in the fetched HTML, there might be a tags such as:

```
<p class="mattFacer">Matt Facer</p>
<p class="mattJones">Matt Jones</p>
<p class="daveSmith">DaveS Smith</p>
```

What I need to do is to read in this HTML and capture any HTML elements which match anything beginning with the word, "matt"

I've tried

```
$html = str_get_html("http://www.testsite.com");
foreach($html->find('matt*') as $element) {
   echo $element;
}
```

but this doesn't work. It returns nothing.

Is it possible to do this? I basically want to search for any HTML element which contains the word "matt". It could be a span, div or p.

I'm at a dead end here!

Comment: With XPath (which I'm not sure if the Simple DOM supports), you'd just do `//p[starts-with(@class,'matt')]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$html = str_get_html("http://www.testsite.com");
foreach($html->find('[class*=matt]') as $element) {
   echo $element;
}
```

Let's try that

Comment: thanks - yes that's worked! Is it possible to do this if I don't know if it's the class name or the id? eg: <p id="mattFacer"> or <p class="mattFacer">

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
foreach(array_merge($html->find('[class*=matt]'),$html->find('[id*=matt]')) as $element) {
    echo $element;
}
```